# Built-in display blinking after trying "1920x1080i" configuration for external display

Tags: 18.04, display, dell

I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04** on a **Dell Inspiron 15 7559** connected with a **LG Tv/Monitor** via HDMI.

I tried to configure the monitor to the 1920x1080i configuration and the interface crashed instantly. At the moment of the bug, I managed to switch back to 1920x1080, but I still had to restart the system to try to make it work properly. After restarting, the built-in display started to blink sporadically. Sometimes it blinks a lot in a short period of time, sometimes it's like 1 blink per minute...

Someone have any idea what could have happened, please??

PS: The LG Monitor works fine.

Answer (score 0):

TVs are notoriously fussy as monitors, and I have seem quite a few reports of erroneous timing information through [EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data), the data from the monitor that tells the video card how to craft the signal.

One workaround is to force specific timing rates through xrandr or your favorite video tool to override faulty EDID information, or to use some tools to rewrite EDID information in the TV.

A search including the exact LG model number plus "EDID" would be a good way to start researching the problem.